# Issues with my wifi after installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers

I am a new Linux user. After installing Ubuntu I couldn't use my wifi anymore.

```
$ lspci -vnn | grep Network
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)

$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Did you install the driver?

Answer (score 1):

Seems when I completely uninstalled Windows from my computer my WLAN network radio was disabled. I simply got to the BIOS and enabled it and it's now ok.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the wireless killswitch is still locked.

Then you could try to activate wireless with the help of "rfkill - tool for enabling and disabling wireless devices":

```
sudo /usr/sbin/rfkill unblock wifi
```

after that you should check if your device appears via ifconfig -a.

Also check the status of the killswitch using:

```
rfkill list
```